# How to remove matching pattern?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

How do i remove my matching pattern from the file?

Everytime the pattern `[my_id=` occurs, it shall be removed without replacement.

For example, the field `[my_id=AB_123456789.1]` should be `AB_123456789.1`.

I already tried, with no result

```
sed '/\[my\_id\=/d'
awk '$(NF-1) /^[protein\_id\=/d'
```

Also it is possible to remove the first n characters from the last but 1 field ($(NF-1)) as an alternative?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Removing `[my_id=` isn't all that's required to turn `[my_id=AB_123456789.1]` into ` AB_123456789.1` as there's a closing `]` disappearing too. Clarify what you need to do and post some representative sample input and expected output. Include what you'd want done with something like `[my_id=AB_12]34]` and `[my_id=AB_12]foo[my_id=AB_12]` if those can occur and any other edge cases you can think of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed 's/\[my_id=\([^]]*\)\]/\1/g' file
```

- `\[my_id=\([^]]*\)\]` looks for this and replaces with the text inside (`\1`).
- `\[my_id=\([^]]*\)\]` means `[my_id=` plus a string not containing `]`, that is caught with the `\(...\)` syntax to be printed back with `\1`.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello [my_id=AB_123456789.1] bye
adf aa [my_id=AB_123456789.1] bbb

$ sed 's/\[my_id=\([^]]*\)\]/\1/g' a
hello AB_123456789.1 bye
adf aa AB_123456789.1 bbb
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this in awk

```
$ cat <<test | awk 'gsub(/\[my_id=|\]/,"")'
  hello [my_id=AB_123456789.1] bye
  adf aa [my_id=AB_123456789.1] bbb
  test

  hello AB_123456789.1 bye
  adf aa AB_123456789.1 bbb
```